# pandas to_datetime couldn't parse string into dates and return strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, strftime, string-to-datetime

I have a `Series` `s` as

```
10241715000
  201709060
   11202017
     112017
     111617
     102417
     110217
    1122018
```

I tried the following code to convert `s` into `datetime`;

```
pd.to_datetime(s.str[:7], format='%-m%d%Y', errors='coerce')
```

but it returned `s` as it is without any conversions been done, I was expecting something like,

```
NaT
NaT
2017-01-20
NaT
NaT
NaT
NaT
2018-01-12
```

The `format` is defined according to `strftime` directives that `%-m`   indicates Month as a decimal number, e.g. 1; `%Y` indicates Year as a decimal number, e.g. 2018. I am wondering what is the issue here. I am using `Pandas 0.22.0` and `Python 3.5`.

UPDATE

```
data = np.array(['10241715000','201709060','11202017','112017','111617','102417',
 '110217','1122018'])

s = pd.Series(data)

pd.to_datetime(s.str[-7:], format='%-m%d%Y', errors='coerce')

0    1715000
1    1709060
2    1202017
3     112017
4     111617
5     102417
6     110217
7    1122018
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be -7 not 7 for `str` slice

```
pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str).str[-7:], format='%m%d%Y', errors='coerce')
Out[189]: 
0          NaT
1          NaT
2   2017-01-20
3   2017-01-01
4          NaT
5          NaT
6          NaT
7   2018-11-02
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Update

```
pd.to_datetime(s.str[-7:].str.pad(8,'left','0'), format='%m%d%Y', errors='coerce')
Out[208]: 
0          NaT
1          NaT
2   2017-01-20
3          NaT
4          NaT
5          NaT
6          NaT
7   2018-01-12
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I have updated my op with some code, and it didn't work.

Comment: what if I want to convert `1122018` to `2018-01-12` instead of `2018-11-02`, what `format` should I define?

Comment: also, I am wondering why it returns the entire series unchanged since `to_datetime` should return `NaT` when it couldn't convert a string to DateTime defined by `format`?